# TypeError: Cannot read property 'secret' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I am fairly new to this, I am using `node.js` to integrate stripe with a firebase `ios` project I am working on. I haven't seen an answer on how to solve this, here is relevant code in my `lib/index.js`:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
// export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
'use strict';


const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const logging = new Logging({
  projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
});
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.secret, {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
});
```

Comment: Where is `functions` coming from?

Comment: Also when I hovered over functions it showed this (if this information is helpful):

Comment: const functions: typeof import("/Users/ericklossner/firecast/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/index")

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant code and error information instead of posting it in comments.

Comment: Never mind I found the answer at https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments, and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env, thank you anyways!

Comment: `functions.config()` returns an object that does not have the `stripe` property (or it is `undefined`), `undefined` doesn't have the `secret` property.

Answer (score 1):

**Set up functions configuration**
If you're using custom functions configuration variables, first run the command to get your custom config (run this within the functions directory) in your local environment:
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator